# jQuery mobile Google map misshaped after the modal dialog closed

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, dialog

I have a problem with jqm and google map.
  I want to use a dialog to get the user's address input and translate the address to lat and lng and set the map's center to the location.
   I use google geocode service and set center function, the problem is:
  When I use safari of iphone4, and chrome desktop version, it is ok, but I use chrome mobile version or firefox ver 15 16 17 even 18 on my android phone(HTC THUN DERBOLT ), the map can not display completely, it only load part map and  the style of map,such as the tool bar at right top map become unnormal.
    In addition there exist a strange problem, if I set the textbox with a initial value, and I don't change the value, the map can display correctly, if I input my address, the google geocode service can get the lat and
lng data but the map seems collapse, it only dispaly part of map and can not drag to the center of the screen.
  What happened and how can I fix it? thank u.

A link with code and screenshot:
  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-dialog-and-google-map-problem.